# Passing value from object string to string

Tags: java, arrays

```
 try {


    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter the continent;");
    String CN = in.readLine();
    String MaxDate="1";
    for(Earthquakerecd e : eqList)
    {
        if( e.getContinent().equals("CN"))
        {
          MaxDate=e.getDate();
        }

        {
            System.out.println( e.toString()); 
        }


    }

     System.out.println( MaxDate); 
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IOException has been caught");
    }
```

This is a simple problem i think. In this problem Maxdate is declared as 1. CN is a string for continent . If the user input matches the continent , then the date should be passed from e.getDate() to Maxdate. In anycase , we should never get the output as 1 , it should be some date from object e. I am always getting 1 for Maxdate. Any possible solutions? is my syntax right?

Comment: have you tried MaxDate=e.getDate().toString()? I'm not savvy with Java, but worths a shot

Comment: the date attribute in object e is a String by the way

Comment: Why is MaxDate a String? Make it same class e.getDate() returns... Also btw, in Java convention is to start variables with lowercase, and classes with uppercase.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting inside the if? Put a breakpoint there.

Comment: @da_scav_from_windy_city You should accept an answer here. Both answers are correct and dbyrne's is very good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you want:

```
if(e.getContinent().equals(CN))
```

Right now you are comparing against the String literal "CN".  You aren't using the variable `CN` for anything.

I'm assuming you meant to insert an `else` after your `if` statement?

Also, in Java it's common to not start your variable names with uppercase letters (name your string `cn` instead of `CN`).

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it this way:

```
try {


    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter the continent;");
    String CN = in.readLine();
    String MaxDate="1";
    for(Earthquakerecd e : eqList)
    {
        if( e.getContinent().equals(CN)) //When you put it with "" the continent value was compared to CN and not from the user input
        {
          MaxDate=e.getDate();
        }

        {
            System.out.println( e.toString()); 
        }


    }

     System.out.println( MaxDate); 
    }

    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IOException has been caught");
    }
```

if that doesnt work, then try by doing the for on this way:

```
for (int i=0; i<eqList.size(); i++) {
     Earthquakerecd e = eqList.get(i);
     //... code ... //
}
```